# How to create a small data set with a data step

Tags: sas

I'm pretty new to SAS coding and I'm just trying to create a data set with a data step but I don't really know how. Its a small set with 4 variables and 3 observations I tried varying things with the code below but I don't know how to do more than one observation at a time.

```
data new_exec;
  ID = 'A';
  Adj_ROA = 1.56;
  Adj_Returns=3.74;
  Total_Assets= 7850;
run;
```

I have 3 ids A B and C then 3 numeric values for each other variable. I just don't know how to make the data set.

Comment: Future note: An import aspect of a `DATA` step is that it performs an implicit loop, be it over the rows of a data set, or the lines of a data file or stated datalines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a data set from 'nothing' isn't as common as you'd think, but a data step is relatively easy to create.

- You use a CARDS or DATALINE statement to indicate that the lines after are your data.
- INFILE is used to specify the type of file being read and delimiter in this example.
- INFORMAT specifies the input format, ie character length 1.
- INPUT reads the data from the CARDS lines.

Note if you're trying to run this, make sure to align it to the edge of the window first.

```
    Data Have;
    infile cards dlm=',';
    length ID $1. AdjROA ADJ_REturns total_Assets 12.;
    input ID  AdjROA ADJ_REturns total_Assets;
    cards;
    A, 1.56, 3.74, 7850
    B, 2.1, 4.5, 2834
    ;;;;
    run;
```

Comment: You have compounded the problem of using `informat` where you should be using `length` or `attrib` by using a numeric informat with a decimal specification.  That will cause SAS to divide the whole numbers in your input data by 100.  Did you really means to set assets to $78.50?

Comment: Why use an INFORMAT to do the work of LENGTH statement?  None of those variables actually require an informat to read that data.

Comment: Bad habit :) You're definitely right though, length or attrib is likely the way to go.

Comment: @Jarod-Bailey  `cards` as in punch cards from mainframe days, haha.  I find myself slowing adopting the newer and equivalent `datalines` statement.

Answer (score 1):

To write multiple observations you can add explicit `OUTPUT` statements.

```
data new_exec;
  ID = 'A';
  Adj_ROA = 1.56;
  Adj_Returns=3.74;
  Total_Assets= 7850;
  output;
  ID = 'B';
  .....
  output;
  ID = 'C';
  .....
  output;
run;
```

Or just place the data in-line with the program and read it with an INPUT statement.  Note use a period for missing values (both numeric and character).

```
data new_exec;
  input id $ Adj_ROA Adj_Returns Total_Assets ;
datalines;
A 1.56 3.74 7850
B 2.1 3.5 5677
C . 4 78909
;
```